# Submitting additional field attributes using Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a redux-form driven form that's being constructed via JSON sent from my backend. This data has specific keys that I need to post back on submit (e.g. filterID). Redux-form appears to keep a fairly minimal state representation of the form/fields. As an example, here's a trivial state dump:

```
{form : {
    myForm: {
        registeredFields: {
            field1: {name: "field1", type: "Field", count: 1},
            field2: {name: "field2", type: "Field", count: 2}
        },
        values: {
            field1: "123"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a built-in way using redux-form that I could have it store additional data in the state (e.g. filterID), or key off of a attribute/prop than name?

```
<Field
      key={somethingunique}
      name={component.name}
      component={component.type}
      filterID={component.id}
/>
```

This would yield something like the following state (move the additional stuff/filterID around anywhere as long as it's present):

```
{form : {
    myForm: {
        registeredFields: {
            field1: {name: "field1", type: "Field", count: 1},
            field2: {name: "field2", type: "Field", count: 2}
        },
        values: {
            field1: "123"
        },
        additionalStuff: {
            field1: {filterID: "abc"}
        },
    }
}
```

My thinking with this approach is that it's easily grabbed in handleSubmit such that I can send it back to the server with a simple stringify.

I can play some games with adding a big object to state and doing lookups on submission, connecting components, etc., but those feel messy.

Comment: If my understanding is correct:

You get from a `form` object from your backend, and you want to add into the `myForm` attribute it a new field `additionnalStuff` when executing your  `handleSubmit` method ?

Comment: Form and myForm are standard redux-form components, but the field definitions come from the backend at initial page load. redux-forms's handleSubmit only appears to send the values piece of the state object back. What I need is for "additionalStuff" to be able to be sent back as well.

I can write extra onSubmit logic easily enough. My hope was that the additionalStuff would be in state somewhere that I could easily grab it or handleSubmit could include it somehow. I could store the entire initial form def in state and do key (field name) matching at submit, but hope there's a better way.

Comment: Did you try `ObjectAssign({}, form, {additionalStuff: {field1: {filterID: "abc"}}})` ?

Comment: Not yet, but that's a good idea. I could try that at the time of the form creation. Would still be cool if there's a way to do it using the redux-form API or via the Field props it provides. However, this might be a workable alternative.

Comment: True, let me know if you get something !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now I don't see a way to solve this with redux-form alone. Instead, when a new form definition comes across, I add it to the global state with a basic action/reducer. In my form's handleSubmit function, I derive a new submission object from the one that redux form constructs by using the name fields as keys in the state form definition. This allows me to easily lookup whatever values are necessary for the backend and submit my new derived object.